# Better errors with Ember

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to have clearer error messages when something is wrong with ember?

For exemple, I have this error `05:10:32,332 Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'eq' could not be found1 vendor.self-4fd4ab06f1f66c1cec72e1ec3a2c99328df792e46fb1fdcd0258c341b30a7c3b.js:24472:0`
. This error is not the subject of the question, this is just an example.

I have no idea where is `eq`. The console indicated this function :

```
  function EmberError() {
    var tmp = Error.apply(this, arguments);

    // Adds a `stack` property to the given error object that will yield the
    // stack trace at the time captureStackTrace was called.
    // When collecting the stack trace all frames above the topmost call
    // to this function, including that call, will be left out of the
    // stack trace.
    // This is useful because we can hide Ember implementation details
    // that are not very helpful for the user.
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(this, _emberMetalCore.default.Error);
    }
    // Unfortunately errors are not enumerable in Chrome (at least), so `for prop in tmp` doesn't work.
    for (var idx = 0; idx < errorProps.length; idx++) {
      this[errorProps[idx]] = tmp[errorProps[idx]];
    }
  }
```

This is not related to my problem.

Obviouly, I searched `eq` in my code and I have no results. I suppose this is in a module but using grep is very ineffective.

Sometimes there is a stacktrace but its not very efficient too. To find an addon or the source in my code in a big `vendor.js` or `myapp.js` is not ideal.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: In my opinion, most of the javascript errors can be found only by enabling the debugger in the console. I would suggest you to enable the debugger, check the call stack trace. Checking the stack trace will certainly give some idea about the error's source.

Comment: I will close this question because I saw than the Chrome console is very more explicit than the firefox one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think something in one of your addons or other third party code is using the [ember-truth-helpers addon](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers).

`vendor.js` typically contains third party code you've imported, not code that you've wrote.

As to the basic issue, it is really up to the maker of the third party code you've imported to document its dependencies and to ensure they are installed when you install that dependency. This really is not a failing of Ember itself, it has told you that there is no helper named `eq` and has given you the line number in the precompiled template where the `eq` was used. You can use the sources tab in Chrome to scroll to line 24472 in vendor.self-4fd4ab06f1f66c1cec72e1ec3a2c99328df792e46fb1fdcd0258c341b30a7c3b.js

Comment: As  I said in the comments, I will delete the question because the trace is more user-friendly with chrome than with firefox. I think it was my problem.